# GCP Pub/Sub logs for internal cloudsqladmin user show query fragments / partial data

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

When exporting logs to Pub/Sub (via Sink, Topic and Subscription) from a GCP Postgresql server (v11), some lines auditing `cloudsqladmin` internal user return what seems to be fragments of SQL queries run on the server. I am looking at them with the Logs viewer.

Examples:

```
 db=cloudsqladmin,user=cloudsqladmin LOG:  00000: statement: WITH max_age AS ("
```

```
textPayload: "2020-11-10 23:30:01.188 UTC [*****]: [5-1] db=*********,user=cloudsqladmin LOG:  00000: statement: ;"  
 timestamp: "2020-11-10T23:30:01.188675Z"
```

It seems to be part of a longer query, but I can't logically attach it to any other adjacent log line.

Does this look like a bug on the GCP side, or am I missing something else here?

Screenshots:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the logs that you have in Cloud Logging?

Comment: Yes, indeed it is method 4 - using a sink, topic and subscription. I will update with screenshots.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: I'm working on this ;)

Comment: Can you please share the method you followed to export your logs from PostgreSQL?. Exporting logs is a broad topic and more information can help us to find the solution most fit your needs.

Perhaps you use one of the following methods?

  - Using the logs viewer [1]
  - Using Stackdriver Logging API [2]
  - Using the command line [3]

I suppose you are following [4] once you have exported them. Please correct me if i’m wrong.

Comment: [1] https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2

[2] https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/tasks/exporting-logs

[3] https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/tools/gcloud-logging

[4] https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/using_exported_logs#pubsub-overview

Comment: method 4, as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I tried several flags, even the pgAudit beta flags, and I didn't find how to flatten the logs. In fact, when you write a multi line query (it's here the case with Cloud SQL, but also the case if you write your app with a multi-line log), it's logged in multi-line and print multiple single line logs.

If you sink the logs into Pub/Sub, you have a message per entry, and if you have multiple line logs, you have multiple messages.

You can mitigate the issue by removing the useless logs trace (system trace, increase the log level,...) and inline your business query to have nice logs.

It's a built in issue, it worth to fill a case [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/).

Comment: Thank you very much. Problem is, I have an external server that imports these logs from pubsub and ingests them - so it's not a matter of display on Logs Viewer - as long as I keep getting these lines, I'll import them to a 3rd party instance, and that will keep on confusing it. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the left arrow in any of the logs you are interested, and then click on "Expand nested fields" you will see your complete query in that log (between other information).

Comment: severity: "INFO"  
 textPayload: "2020-12-04 21:17:10.579 UTC [2796009]: [637-1] db=cloudsqladmin,user=cloudsqladmin LOG:  00000: statement: WITH max_age AS ("  
 timestamp: "2020-12-04T21:17:10.579388Z"  
}

Comment: What I was saying, the full log is exported like that to a 3rd party. I am not missing anything.